# Python function loop through each list value and insert into string

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop

I have a list of values that I would like to loop through and insert into a `"""` string statement. But I am new to for loops and not exactly sure what the best approach is to insert list values efficiently.

I have a list -

```
subqueries = ['name','name2','name3']
```

And a string statement -

```
"""SELECT * FROM <insert name from list here> WHERE id=weather"""
```

To insert the name, I'd like to create a function like this -

```
def sub_view(qry, subqueries):
    qry_list = []
    for sub in subqueries:
        qry_list = qry + """SELECT * FROM""" + subqueries + """ WHERE id=weather"""
    return qry_list
```

to get -

```
name = qry + """SELECT * FROM name WHERE id=weather"""
name2 = qry + """SELECT * FROM name2  WHERE id=weather"""
name3 = qry + """SELECT * FROM name3 WHERE id=weather"""
```

How can I efficiently do this?

Comment: maybe read up on f strings first?

Answer (score 1):

you can use format strings, using "f" before starts a string, and using your variable
inside `{}`, like this: `{sub}`,
then use the `.append()` function to add to your list.

```
for sub in subqueries:
    qry_list.append(qry + f"SELECT * FROM {sub} WHERE id=weather")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [f strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Also your function has a tiny error, the corrected and formatted version is:

```
def sub_view(qry, subqueries):
    qry_list = []
    for sub in subqueries:
        qry_list = f"{qry} SELECT * FROM {sub} WHERE id=weather"
        return qry_list
```

Comment: these are really helpful answers, how can I break them out individually? like name, name2, name3 variables?

Comment: Could you describe it more? What do you mean by breaking them out individually? I guess, you don't know to access a list element. 

call your function and assign it to a value:
`my_queries = sub_view(qry, subqueries)
print(my_queries[0]) # name
print(my_queries[1]) # name2`

Comment: so each subquery becomes it's own string variable, tried to break it out in the output in question description

Answer (score 0):

you can use "lambda" like this:

```
def sub_view(qry, subqueries):
    return list(map(lambda s: qry + """SELECT * FROM """ + s + """ WHERE id=weather""", subqueries))
```

also you can use "for" like this:

```
def sub_view(qry, subqueries):
    qry_list = []
    for sub in subqueries:
        #qry_list.append(qry + """SELECT * FROM """ + sub + """ WHERE id=weather""")
        qry_list.append("""%s SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = weather""" % (qry, sub))
    return qry_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subqueries1 = ['name','name2','name3']

def sub_view(qry, subqueries):
  qry_list = []
  for sub in subqueries:
    qry_list.append(qry + """SELECT * FROM""" + sub + """ WHERE id=weather""")
  return qry_list
  
  
x=sub_view('qry',subqueries1)
for i in x:
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your objective is because the query strings don't look that useful, however, you can create a list of queries containing the substitutions using a list comprehension:

```
def sub_view(qry, subqueries):
    return [f"{qry} SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE id='weather'" for table in subqueries]

>>> subqueries = ['name','name2','name3']
>>> sub_view('Some prefix string', subqueries)
["Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name WHERE id='weather'", "Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name2 WHERE id='weather'", "Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name3 WHERE id='weather'"]
```

This will return a list. To bind each of the queries to a variable requires that you know how many items there will be in the list and their order. You could manually code it like this:

```
>>> name, name2, name3 = sub_view('Some prefix string', subqueries)
>>> name
"Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name WHERE id='weather'"
>>> name2
"Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name2 WHERE id='weather'"
>>> name3
"Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name3 WHERE id='weather'"
```

Given that you need prior knowledge of the variable count you could just use the list. Call it `names` and refer to the "variables" by index:

```
>>> names = sub_view('Some prefix string', subqueries)
>>> names[0]
"Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name WHERE id='weather'"
>>> names[1]
"Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name2 WHERE id='weather'"
...
```

Or use a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary:

```
def sub_view(qry, subqueries):
    return {table: f"{qry} SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE id='weather'" for table in subqueries}

>>> queries = sub_view('Some prefix string', subqueries)
>>> queries
{'name': "Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name WHERE id='weather'", 'name2': "Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name2 WHERE id='weather'", 'name3': "Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name3 WHERE id='weather'"}

>>> queries['name']
"Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name WHERE id='weather'"
>>> queries['name2']
"Some prefix string SELECT * FROM name2 WHERE id='weather'"
...
```

This last example is probably the closest to what you want. It will handle any number of queries and you can still access the individual queries by using the name as the key for a dictionary lookup.

Comment: thank you, the objective is helpful for me ... i suppose there isn't a more automated way to loop through and create these string variables?

Comment: A one line list or dictionary comprehension is about as succinct and automated as it gets. The dictionary comprehension is probably best: it takes the list of tables/subqueries and the `qry` value and returns a dictionary that you can use to lookup the strings by names provided in the subqueries list. To access the results by variable names requires exactly the same amount of information as does a dictionary, and it requires additional code to perform the assignments, so there is no automation advantage in doing so.